# Select default if no rows return

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Column1 
FROM Table1 
WHERE PKColumn = SomeValue
```

I am selecting just *one* column, my query will return only 0 or 1 row for sure. I want to select some default values like `Some Default` if no row returned otherwise the returned value.

I tried something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) = 1 THEN Column1 ELSE 'Some Default' END AS Column1 
FROM Table1 
WHERE PKColumn = SomeValue  
GROUP BY Column1
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do it in single SQL statement?

Comment: I think you need to use `EXISTS` instead ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the
>   first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE PK = SomeValue), 'DefaultValue')
```

or like this:

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT = 3 -- Default value
SELECT TOP 1 @ReturnValue = Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE PK = SomeValue
SELECT @ReturnValue
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE PKColumn = SomeValue) THEN Column1 
         ELSE 'Some Default' END AS Column1
FROM t;
```

---

Or using `EXISTS` with `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'Some Default' As Column1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE PKColumn = SomeValue)
UNION ALL
SELECT Column1
FROM t
WHERE PKColumn = SomeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     [Column1] = ISNULL([t2].[Column1], 'Some Default')
FROM 
    [Table1]    AS  [t1]
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT
             [Column1]
        FROM
            [Table1]
        WHERE
                [PKColumn] = [t1].[PKColumn]              
    )           AS  [t2]         
WHERE 
        [t1].[PKColumn] = 'SomeValue';
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps can try using LEN instead of COUNT to check if Column1 has value?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Column1) > 0 THEN Column1 ELSE 'Some Default' END AS Column1 
FROM Table1 
WHERE PKColumn = SomeValue  
GROUP BY Column1
```